# ABSOLUTE convergence of Operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

Is there a meaning of *absolute* convergence of operators? In my exercises i am asked to proof that a power series of operators converges absolutely in the space of bounded operators. But i have no clue what *absolute* convergence of operators could mean since there is no absolute value of an operator.

Comment: In this context, it should mean that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lVert T_k\rVert<\infty$ (where $T_k$ is the sequence that "converges absolutely").